# Necesito arrastrar una formula hasta una celda determinada vía Excel

Tags: vba

Estoy intentando crear una macro para facilitarme el trabajo pero no consigo arrastrar la formula hasta la ultima celda escrita.

Consigo que se arrastre hasta la ultima celda escrita en ese momento (Fila 29), pero  cuanto introduzco datos nuevos la macro no funciona.

Hasta ahora mi macro es la siguiente:

Sub Arrastrar_formula()

'
' Arrastro la formula $B3&$C3&$E3&$G3
'

```
Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = _
    "=$B3&$C3&$E3&$G3"
Range("A3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A3:A29"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

End Sub

Realmente lo ideal sería que sólo se introduzca la fórmula en la primera celda de los datos nuevos y que arrastre la formula desde ahí, para que así no deba hacer el calculo desde la primera celda (A3).

Agradeceria vuestra ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A29")

 .FormulaLocal = "=$B3&$C3&$E3&$G3"

End With
```

Si quieres que cada vez que ejecutes la macro te arrastre la fórmula hasta la última fila con datos independientemente de cual sea lo que tienes que hacer es primero encontrar esa última fila:

```
Dim ufila as Long
Dim sht as Worksheet

Set sht = Thisworkbook.Sheets("nombre_hoja") 'En nombre_hoja pon el nombre de tu hoja
ufila = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'En este caso VBA determinará la última fila teniendo en cuenta si hay datos o no en la columna B. 

With ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A" & ufila)

       .FormulaLocal = "=$B3&$C3&$E3&$G3"

End With
```